# Get Outcome of the "start and wait for approval" Vs get the ResponsesComments. For the later, Power Automate will automatically add a "Apply to Each"

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, approval-process, microsoft-flow

I have the following "Start and wait for approval" step inside my automated flow:

[image]

Then I wanted to send an email containing the Outcome of the "start and wait for approval" + the Comment added by the first user for the "start and wait for approval", as follow:

[image]

But my question is why Power Automate will automatically add a "Apply to Each" when we try to reference the Responses Comments, while it will not do the same if we try to reference  the Outcome?

Do both need "Apply to each"? or both do not? as they are the same context; one return the comment and the other represent the action taken (Proceed or Pending) in our case?? Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power automate approval action returns the response like below:

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "responder": {
        "id": "4ad30135-cdee-4490-b9ef-1714f4724bb3",
        "displayName": "Ganesh Sanap",
        "email": "ganesh@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
        "tenantId": "2e5fa22e-a7c7-45fe-8cd4-f2d2214593dc",
        "userPrincipalName": "ganesh@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      "requestDate": "2022-02-17T04:46:54Z",
      "responseDate": "2022-02-17T04:47:26Z",
      "approverResponse": "Approve",
      "comments": "Approval comments added."
    },
    {
      "responder": {
        "id": "4ad30135-cdee-4490-b9ef-1714f4724bb3",
        "displayName": "ABC",
        "email": "abc@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
        "tenantId": "2e5fa22e-a7c7-45fe-8cd4-f2d2214593dc",
        "userPrincipalName": "abc@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      "requestDate": "2022-02-17T04:46:54Z",
      "responseDate": "2022-02-17T04:47:26Z",
      "approverResponse": "Approve",
      "comments": "Approval comments added."
    },
    {
      "responder": {
        "id": "4ad30135-cdee-4490-b9ef-1714f4724bb3",
        "displayName": "XYZ",
        "email": "xyz@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
        "tenantId": "2e5fa22e-a7c7-45fe-8cd4-f2d2214593dc",
        "userPrincipalName": "xyz@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      "requestDate": "2022-02-17T04:46:54Z",
      "responseDate": "2022-02-17T04:47:26Z",
      "approverResponse": "Approve",
      "comments": "Approval comments added."
    }
  ],
  "responseSummary": "Approver: Ganesh Sanap, ganesh@tenant.onmicrosoft.com\r\nResponse: Approve\r\nRequest Date: Thursday, February 17, 2022 4:46:54 AM\r\nResponse Date: Thursday, February 17, 2022 4:47:26 AM",
  "completionDate": "2022-02-17T04:47:26Z",
  "outcome": "Approve",
  "name": "b0c3824a-b8cb-4f62-9527-ef7a0fe34e3c",
  "title": "Approval - First to respond",
  "requestDate": "2022-02-17T04:46:53Z",
  "expirationDate": "9999-12-31T23:59:59Z"
}
```

It has `responses` array within approval action output body which stores the `approverResponse` & `comments` from each approver (even when there is only one approver). So, when you try to fetch the `comments` property, flow automatically adds it inside apply to each loop.

And `outcome` is the final outcome of the approval action which is outside of responses array. Hence, when you try to fetch the `outcome` property, flow will not add it inside apply to each loop.

So, if you want to fetch the comments of approver you must use "apply to each" and as you are using "Wait for one response" approval, you can either use `approverResponse` or `outcome`, both will give you the same results.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so even if we have multiple outcomes, for example 2 approve + 1 reject.. those responses will be inside a single string and not inside an array? am i correct?

Comment: Responses can be multiple, but final outcome will be only one. Let's say you use "Everyone must approve" approval with 5 approvers, when all 5 approves, outcome will be "Approve" and if any one from 5 approvers rejects, outcome will be "Reject". But, you can get the response of individual approver from `responses` array using `approverResponse` property (check the JSON example given in answer to related the properties).

Comment: thanks a lot for your useful reply.. but i have these 2 extra question; 1) can we configure how the final outcome will be ? for example can we define that unless 2 or more users reject to have the final outcome as Reject, so if only one user reject to consider the final outcome as approve? 2) second question, how the final outcome will be calculated in case we have custom responses? Thanks

Comment: We cannot customize how the final outcome will be in case we use predefined Approve/Reject and and First 2 approval options. Check this video for more information on Approvals & different types: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZnI0_atYUo

Comment: ok thanks but what about the final outcomes when we have custom responses instead of approve/reject?

Comment: In case of custom responses, you get all the responses in outcome property like: `"outcome": "CustomResponse1, CustomResponse2, CustomResponse3"`. I will suggest you check above video once which covers this scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently building a quick approval system for my org and developed a more polished way of doing this without loops & with better formatting...

[image]

Code to copy & control+V paste into a new action menu "My clipboard" section

```
{"id":"1675f896-3d03-4395-a438-6dac8e39bf6e","brandColor":"#8C3900","connectionReferences":{"shared_office365users":{"connection":{"id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_office365users/connections/88b73cab99bd4598bfce9895cb9a47b2"}},"shared_office365users_1":{"connection":{"id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_office365users/connections/88b73cab99bd4598bfce9895cb9a47b2"}},"shared_office365":{"connection":{"id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_office365/connections/shared-office365-67f10a94-c084-4840-baf8-1be9-5c063787"}},"shared_microsoftforms":{"connection":{"id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_microsoftforms/connections/shared-microsoftform-a6fc78b2-11a3-41b2-bf04-1ebf5cf143c6"}},"shared_sharepointonline":{"connection":{"id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_sharepointonline/connections/shared-sharepointonl-60d1f27e-bd8b-43f2-a8ad-a7be60200f79"}},"shared_approvals":{"connection":{"id":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_approvals/connections/shared-approvals-39fa7c48-bf13-4c6a-a5cd-45d1-5cdc5d95"}}},"connectorDisplayName":"Control","icon":"data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMzIiIGhlaWdodD0iMzIiIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDMyIDMyIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPg0KIDxwYXRoIGQ9Im0wIDBoMzJ2MzJoLTMyeiIgZmlsbD0iIzhDMzkwMCIvPg0KIDxwYXRoIGQ9Im04IDEwaDE2djEyaC0xNnptMTUgMTF2LTEwaC0xNHYxMHptLTItOHY2aC0xMHYtNnptLTEgNXYtNGgtOHY0eiIgZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIvPg0KPC9zdmc+DQo=","isTrigger":false,"operationName":"Get_responders_and_comments_from_Start_and_wait_for_an_approval","operationDefinition":{"type":"Scope","actions":{"SelectMoreApprovalDetails":{"type":"Select","inputs":{"from":"@outputs('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['body/responses']","select":"@concat('Reviewer: ', item()?['responder']?['displayName'], decodeUriComponent('%0A'), 'Response: ', item()?['approverResponse'], decodeUriComponent('%0A'), 'Comment: ', item()?['comments'])"},"runAfter":{},"description":"Enter the Responses dynamic content from your \"Start and wait for an approval\" action in the From field","metadata":{"operationMetadataId":"fdadb5f3-98e8-40a1-9da1-360477370c9b"}},"RespondersAndComments":{"type":"Compose","inputs":"@join(body('SelectMoreApprovalDetails'), decodeUriComponent('%0A%0A'))","runAfter":{"SelectMoreApprovalDetails":["Succeeded"]}}},"runAfter":{"Start_and_wait_for_an_approval":["Succeeded"]},"description":"Will get each responder & their comments for an action named \"Start and wait for an approval\". If your action name is different, like \"Start and wait for an approval 2\" you need to update the From field of the 1st Select action."}}
```