# Flow (Power Automate) that needs a group of people to all respond with updates

Tags: power-automate, flow

I have a flow that I have tried to create 2 ways but neither was acceptable. The scenario is:

1. A user clicks a button to start a flow
2. The user enters the name(s) of the person/people who will approve/reject/request a change
3. The approvers must receive an email notifying them they have to respond to this document/flow
4. The flow must ensure all of the approvers respond (any response is
   acceptable)
5. The status of who has/has not responded with their answer must be written to a SharePoint list so everyone knows who has not taken action yet

I first tried this by creating a switch statement that had an approval with "Custom Responses - Wait for one response". The problem is that if three or four approvers needed to take action the approval wasn't able to ensure everyone had responded because that was only one approval for one person.

The second concept I tried was with "Custom Responses - Wait for all responses" which ensured everyone responded in some way. The problem is that this action stalls until everyone does something so there is no way to update everyone regarding who had, or had not, responded so far and what their responses are.

If anyone has any ideas on another concept to try please let me know[image]

Comment: Which action are you using for your approval step? If you use "Create an approval" instead of "Start and Wait for an approval" it should continue running the rest of your flow steps

Comment: Check if this post helps to capture the approval responses: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300523/get-outcome-of-the-start-and-wait-for-approval-vs-get-the-responsescomments-f/304189#304189

Comment: Thank you for responding. The link Ganesh sent is more about getting comments after all users have responded. I am using the "create an approval" step. I added a picture above to explain my concept.

Comment: You are using the "Start and wait for approval action" (as can be seen in your screenshot). There is another action called "Create an approval". This will start the approval process but continue with the rest of your flow.